# How do I use a dictionary value as a key name in another dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts like so:

```
[
    {
        'flight_id': 'f123',
        'pax': 234,
        'airline': 'Foo Airways'
    },
    {
        'flight_id': 'f124',
        'pax': 200,
        'airline': 'Bar Airways'
    }
]
```

I want to dynamically build a new data structure from that, that looks like this:

```
{
    'f123': {'pax': 234, 'airline': 'Foo Airways'},
    'f124': {'pax': 200, 'airline': 'Bar Airways'}
}
```

Basically, I need a way to turn a dictionary value into the key name in a new dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @acattle Nothing. I'm new to Python.  
I wonder, why the downvotes? Is this not an "appropriate" programming question, or is SO only for asking expert-level questions these days?

Comment: No, you're allowed to ask any question you want (as long as it fits within the scope of SO) but it's better if you talk about all the research you've done, any attempts, or ideas you have. That way we can help you learn where you went wrong, not just show you the answer. It's more satisfying for us and it's more helpful for you. Questions that get downvoted typically "[do] not show any research effort" (mouse over the downvote button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
flights = dict((f.pop('flight_id'), f) for f in flights)
```

That will replace the previous data structure.

Python 2.7+ has dict comprehensions:

```
flights = {f.pop('flight_id'): f for f in flights}
```

Comment: @DSM: oh because its a generator. Generator comprension :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = [
...     {
...         'flight_id': 'f123',
...         'pax': 234,
...         'airline': 'Foo Airways'
...     },
...     {
...         'flight_id': 'f124',
...         'pax': 200,
...         'airline': 'Bar Airways'
...     }
... ]
>>> itms = [x.pop('flight_id') for x in d]
>>> dict(zip(itms,d))
{'f124': {'pax': 200, 'airline': 'Bar Airways'}, 'f123': {'pax': 234, 'airline':
 'Foo Airways'}}
```